# what does the parameter(-1,) in python mean?

Tags: python, numpy

```
data = np.loadtxt('In_file', dtype=np.float, delimiter=',')

x_test, y_test = np.split(data, (-1, ), axis=1)
```

What i konw is this line of code divided the data into two parts,but what does the parameter (-1,) mean?

Answer (score 2):

a tuple with a value of -1 on index 0

Answer (score 2):

Often when indexing, `-1` means, `from-the-end`.  `(-1,)` is a 1 element tuple.

Its meaning in this context is a little harder to imagine, but a simple test makes it clearer:

```
In [304]: x=np.arange(10)
In [305]: np.split(x, (-1,))
Out[305]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), array([9])]
```

It split the array, with a last part that is 1 element long. Don't get confused by the tuple notation; it's really expecting a list, e.g. `[-1]`:

```
In [307]: np.split(x, [-1])
Out[307]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]), array([9])]
```

We can split with 3 items in the last array, or 3 items in the first.

```
In [308]: np.split(x, [-3])
Out[308]: [array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), array([7, 8, 9])]
In [309]: np.split(x, [3])
Out[309]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Or a 3 way split, with 3 items in the first, 2 in the last:

```
In [311]: np.split(x, [3,-2])
Out[311]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([8, 9])]
```

this last split is actually performed with 3 indexing ranges:

```
In [313]: x[0:3],x[3:-2],x[-2:]
Out[313]: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([3, 4, 5, 6, 7]), array([8, 9]))
```

Your case is a 2d array, and it's doing the split on columns. So in effect `y_test` is the last column, and `x_test` is the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Split the array along the column axis on the values in the tuple. `(-1, )` will split it 2 parts.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(9.0).reshape(3,3)
print x,'\n'

a=np.split(x, (-1, ), axis=1)

print a,'\n'
print a[0],'\n'
print a[1],'\n'
```

Output:

```
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 3.  4.  5.]
 [ 6.  7.  8.]] 

[array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 3.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  7.]]), array([[ 2.],
       [ 5.],
       [ 8.]])] 

[[ 0.  1.]
 [ 3.  4.]
 [ 6.  7.]] 

[[ 2.]
 [ 5.]
 [ 8.]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.split(ary, indices_or_sections, axis=0)
```

Indices_or_sections : int or 1-D array
If indices_or_sections is an integer, N, the array will be divided into N equal arrays along axis. If such a split is not possible, an error is raised.
If indices_or_sections is a 1-D array of sorted integers, the entries indicate where along axis the array is split. 
If an index exceeds the dimension of the array along axis, an empty sub-array is returned correspondingly. [Source documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)